# I am not able to parse the json data having two dictionaries , I am getting response like the below while i am hiiting url in the browser

Tags: ios

```
{
    "type": "1",
    "item": "Order created successfully.",
    "order_id": "7"
} 
{
    "multicast_id": 9215180185089775977,
    "success": 1,
    "failure": 0,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [{
        "message_id": "0:1465191236656122%86acb02ff9fd7ecd"
    }]
}
```

Comment: so do you think we are predict what is your JSON parsing URL based on your response log lol. Please put what have you trying so far code and url

Comment: Share your code so we can help you

Comment: I want to fetch type and success Values from above response, but while parsing the jsondata into the dictionary ,the dictonary giving  nil.

Comment: How are you fetching it? have you write any code?

Comment: I think this is not your proper json response.. so can you post full json or change your response.

Comment: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Garbage at end." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Garbage at end.}

Comment: getting this error

Comment: jsonData=[[NSDictionary alloc] init];
                    NSError *er;
             jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization
                                JSONObjectWithData:urlData
                                options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                error:&er];
jsonData returns nil

Comment: are you getting urlData or is it nil as well?

Comment: If the posted response is what you getting from server , its invalid , two dictionaries must be separated by  "," and these must be elements of an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are trying to get json response seems ok. Apparently, there is an invalid response from server. What you have posted seems invalid json. The response from server should be something like

```
[
  {
   "type": "1",
   "item": "Order created successfully.",
   "order_id": "7"
  }, 

  {
   "multicast_id": 9215180185089775977,
   "success": 1,
   "failure": 0,
   "canonical_ids": 0,
   "results": [{
       "message_id": "0:1465191236656122%86acb02ff9fd7ecd"
   }]
  }
]
```

Once you get data like that, you can store it as an array of dictionaries.

Answer (score -1):

there are two dictionary in your json so you have to add these dictionaries into your array and you can call your dictionaries element by their key  name.

example:[[array objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:name]; and so On.......

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: you can help me with your answer